# how to apply style for 'ul' and 'li' and 'a' in same class?

Tags: html, css, class, html-lists

i am new to front end development..
i want to apply style for `<ul>` and `<li>` and also for `<a>` in same class.. is it possible ?

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css"> 
.menu ul, li, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Customers</a>
            <a href="#">Locations</a>
            <a href="#">Fare</a>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes it's possible...

```
.menu ul { /*css here*/ }
.menu ul li { /*css here*/ }
.menu ul li a { /*css here*/ }
```

or

```
.menu ul, .menu ul li, .menu ul li a { /*css here*/ }
```

or

```
.menu ul, .menu li, .menu a { /*css here*/ }
```